# Shorten a Like statement in VBA

Tags: vba

Is there any way to shorten this Like statement in VBA

```
If ibasic Like "A1*" Or ibasic Like "A2*" Or ibasic Like "A3*" Or ibasic Like "A4*" Or ibasic Like "A5*" Or ibasic Like "A6*" Or ibasic Like "A7*" Or ibasic Like "A8*" Or ibasic Like "B1*" Or ibasic Like "B2*" Or ibasic Like "B3*" Or ibasic Like "B4*" Or ibasic Like "B5*" Or ibasic Like "B6*" Or ibasic Like "B7*" Or ibasic Like "B8*" Or ibasic Like "F1*" Or ibasic Like "F2*" Or ibasic Like "F3*" Or ibasic Like "F4*" Or ibasic Like "F5*" Or ibasic Like "F6*" Or ibasic Like "F7*" Or ibasic Like "F8*" Or ibasic Like "C1*" Or ibasic Like "S1*" Then
```

Comment: Put the conditions in an array and loop the array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine all these comparisons in just two statements by making use of brackets, which match any one character inside them:

```
If ibasic Like "[ABF][1-8]*" OR ibasic Like "[CS]1*" Then
```

The dash expresses a range of characters here.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the option in an `Array()`, loop through them in a separate function and return the result:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myInput As String: myInput = "A243"
    Dim myLikes As Variant

    myLikes = Array("A1*", "A2*", "A3*")
    Debug.Print CheckLikes(myLikes, myInput)

End Sub

Public Function CheckLikes(myLikes As Variant, myInput As String) As Boolean
    Dim myVars As Variant

    For Each myVars In myLikes
        If myInput Like myVars Then
            CheckLikes = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: You beat my typing! +1

Comment: @QHarr - I practice.

Comment: Lol. Made me think of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populaire_(film); which is a great film btw. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6upoz9I7eg

Comment: @QHarr - seems like an interesting plot, will check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can list the alternatives with a `Select Case` statement, having first extracted the left two characters:

```
data = "A100"

Select Case Left(data, 2)
    Case "A1", "A2": 'etc.
        Debug.Print True
    Case Else:
        Debug.Print False
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
If CBool(InStr(1, "|A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|A6|", "|" & Left(ibasic, 2) & "|", vbTextCompare)) Then
    'true, do something ...
End If
```

Comment: The scrolling makes the second part not visible and it is the important one.

Comment: I'm just not seeing it although I added a trailing pipe after A6.

Comment: yup, I have missed the pipe on the edit, sry. What kind of monitor are you using? Or a smart phone?

Comment: Surface Pro (currently on battery saver) and a pair of old eyes.

Comment: OK, now I think I understand; you cut down the available 'likes' to show the substring construction which is important. Originally I thought I got something wrong. Good call, I should have abbreviated it myself.

Comment: Yup, this is why I did it. Had to scroll too much to the right otherwise.